# pdflatex doesn't seem to recognize where beamer.cls is

Tags: beamer, pdftex

(I'm relatively new to Latex)

I'm trying to compile a simple `beamer` LaTeX document using the following line:

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode example.tex
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

! LaTeX Error: File `beamer.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.12 \begin
           {document}^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on example.log.
```

From this output, it initially seemed to me that beamer was not installed. After trying `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended` to make sure I had beamer, I received a message saying that this package was already installed in my computer. Then, using `locate beamer.cls` indeed pointed to `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls` as the file location. From these operations, I think that `pdflatex` is unable to recognize where `beamer.cls` is and might be looking instead on a different directory. This is possibly due to several updates and reinstallations of `texlive` that I did in the past.

Is there a way I can tell `pdflatex` where to look for packages to possibly solve this issue?
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: perhaps you need to run `mktexlsr` to update the file name database. Btw: don't use `-interaction=nonstopmode` if you just start with latex. If is much better if it stops directly at the first error.

Comment: LaTeX does not use `locate` to find stuff, try `kpsewhich beamer.cls`, theis looks for files the same way LaTeX looks for files. As Ulrike mentions, the file may be on disk, but the database where latex looks for files might not have been properly updated (searching once and building a lookup table is much much faster than searching the disk on every compilation)